# Not getting correct permission as per defined in scope in oAuth2 access token when trying to sign in using google

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am trying to sign in with google using AWS Cognito federation inside the user pool. My main goal is to get an access token and refresh token to call Google APIs on my server. I added the required scope and got permission as well, but the access token I am getting is not containing that extra permission in my case that's google calendar, and when I am trying to access calendar API getting a 401 Unauthorized error even.

I used Amplify library on React side to request tokens.
Amplify config:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'us-east-2',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'us-east-2_xxxxxxx',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

   

    // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
    oauth: {
      domain: 'calendar-google.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: [
        'phone',
        'email',
        'profile',
        'openid',
        'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
      ],
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      responseType: 'code',
    },
  },
});
```

Scope used in cognito config

```
profile email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeuTY.png)

[image]

Comment: Try logging in from a different source. Maybe your old refresh token is still generating an outdated access token.

Comment: May be this issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/684 the token of Amplify has the wrong scope (aws.cognito.signin.user.admin). But there seems no solution so far.

Comment: I got a similar issue and solved it. Maybe that would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236173/how-to-get-the-access-token-from-amplify-which-works-with-api-gateway-and-cognit/70256897#70256897