# How to get the access token from Amplify which works with API gateway and cognito?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to get the right token from Amplify (using Vue) to login into API Gateway with Cognito.

So far I tried those:

```
  Auth.currentSession().then(data => {
    console.log('idToken: %s',data.idToken.jwtToken)
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  Auth.currentSession().then(data => {
    console.log('accessToken: ',data.accessToken)
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  Auth.currentSession().then(data => {
    console.log('jwtToken: ',data.accessToken.jwtToken)
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But if I copy them to postman, none of them work.

The only thing which works, if I take the access_token which I get back from the test login UI.

--edit--

It looks like the provided token from Amplify has the wrong scope:

```
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
```

The token from hostet UI is like this:

```
  "scope": "phone openid profile email",
```

Hint: Can be decoded on https://jwt.io/

There is a discussion about that for Amplify:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/684

But I've got no solution so far

Comment: You need to be chaining the methods not accessing properties on the method.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, there seems to be no solution to set a different scope in Amplify.

Now I did the following:

Set in API Gateway this scope:

```
aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
```

(not sure if this is a security issue!?)

Now I can access the lambda. As I need the EMail-Address of the user, I do in Python a request to cognito with username (which is delivered by the access token).

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
user_details = client.admin_get_user(
    Username=user_name,
    UserPoolId=user_pool_id
)

logger.warning("user_details: {}".format(user_details))
```

The id_token can not be used as it does not hold the required scope information to pass the API gateway.